# o-gradient doesn't work on Mac and Linux

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a website and want to make a gradient without an image. It works, but only for Windows, not Mac or Linux. Can you tell me why ? http://www.europe-football.net/login.php this is a website and you can check if you have mac that Register and Log in Button gradient won't be displayed, but if you have Windows it will be displayed.

Here is the html code:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="button" />
```

Here is the css code:

```
     #button {

    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #de4c4a, #cc3727);

    }
```

I'd really appriciate your help

Comment: why does your link go to google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -o- gradient is used for Opera browsers. Chances are you are using a different browser on the mac?  Try using this tool to create your gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

And if you want to really learn more about them read this article: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: thanks. Yes I use Opera for windows, and I used Mozilla on Mac.

Comment: @sandrovardiashvili if your new to stackoverflow,you should accept the answer if it fixed your problem.. check the tick mark next to the answer which you find most suitable and best fix for your problem..